# How do I use my own occlusion ML model with ARKit?

Tags: swift, arkit, metal, coreml, realitykit

ARKit has [built-in people occlusion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/camera_lighting_and_effects/occluding_virtual_content_with_people), which you can enable with something like

```swift
        guard let config = arView.session.configuration as? ARWorldTrackingConfiguration else {
            fatalError("Unexpectedly failed to get the configuration.")
        }
        guard ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsFrameSemantics(.personSegmentationWithDepth) else {
            fatalError("People occlusion is not supported on this device.")
        }
        config.frameSemantics.insert(.personSegmentationWithDepth)
        arView.session.run(config)
```

I would like to provide my own binary segmentation model ("binary" as in person/not-person for each pixel), presumably using CoreML, instead of using whatever Apple is using to segment people because I want to occlude something else instead of people. How do I do this? Is there a straightforward way to do this or will I have to re-implement parts of the rendering pipeline? They show some code about how to use people segmentation with a custom Metal renderer in [this WWDC 2019 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/607/) (starts around 9:30) but it's not clear to me how to use my own model based on that, and I would prefer to use ARKit/RealityKit instead of implementing my own rendering (I am a mere mortal).

Comment: I haven't looked to much into custom shaders in RealityKit 2 but a shader in RealityKit or SceneKit are probably your best bet. Feed the ARFrames into your model and write a custom shader that alters the depth buffer.

Comment: Don't fear Metal.  There are countless example projects to get you started. Once you get the basics, it's just awesomely powerful stuff.